# Holomorphic Poisson brackets on Fano manifolds

Tags: poisson-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for the  preprint

> **A. Bondal,**   Noncommutative
>   deformations and Poisson brackets on
>   projective spaces. **Preprint MPI/93-67**

which I could not find online. Does anyone have an eletronic version of it ?

I am interested in the conjecture made there which predicts that  the locus where the rank of a holomorphic Poisson bracket on a Fano manifold is smaller than $k$ has dimension strictly greater than $k$, see for instance  Section 2 of Beauville's [problem list in holomorphic symplectic geometry](http://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4321). Some progress has been made by Polishchuck  in  *[Algebraic Geometry of Poisson Brackets](http://www.springerlink.com/content/b6720722hv888134/)* (Journal of Mathematical Sciences 84 no. 5, 1997); and by Druel in  *[Structures de Poisson sur les variétés algébriques de dimension 3](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9803069)*
(Bull. Soc. Mat. France  127, 1999).

Any further references on this conjecture will be welcome.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF02399197](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02399197) ([Zbl 0995.37057](https://zbmath.org/0995.37057)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprint of Bondal can be found here:

http://www.mi.ras.ru/~akuznet/math/Bondal%20Non-commutative%20deformations%20and%20Poisson%20brackets%20on%20projective%20spaces.pdf

Another related reference is the following paper

Fano threefolds with sections in $Ω^1(1)$, by Priska Jahnke and Ivo Radloff.

Comment: The link provided is a scanned copy. A searchable copy is also available directly from MPI: http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/preblob/4912